# How can I save DOM elements inside of a javaScript object? I want to update the page by updating the object

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How can I save DOM elements inside of a javaScript object? I want to update the page by updating the object.

Bellow I created and Added elements to the website using a for loop. I want to save some of those elements inside some objects properties so that I can update the html in the page by updating the textContent of the property value in the object.

```
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= numberOfPlayers ; i++ ){
    //create object for each player.
    var name = nameInputArray[i].value;
    players["player" + i] = {
      name: name,
      score: 0,
      fireStreak: 0,
      xStreak: 0,
      html: {}
    }

    //Create a Player box for each player.
    var playerBox= document.createElement('div');
    playerBox.classList.add('player_box');
    document.getElementById('player-box-container').appendChild(playerBox);

    var playerName = document.createElement('div');
    playerName.textContent = players["player" + i].name;
    playerName.classList.add('player_names');
    playerBox.appendChild(playerName);

    var playerScoreHeading = document.createElement('div');
    playerScoreHeading.classList.add('player_score_heading');
    playerScoreHeading.textContent = "Player Score:";
    playerBox.appendChild(playerScoreHeading);

    var playerScoreDiv = document.createElement('div');
    playerScoreDiv.classList.add('player_score');
    playerBox.appendChild(playerScoreDiv);

    var playerScoreNumber = document.createElement('span');
    playerScoreNumber.classList.add('player_score_number');
    playerScoreNumber.textContent = players["player" + i].score;

    playerScoreNumber.id = "player_score_number_" + i;



    playerScoreDiv.appendChild(playerScoreNumber);
    //THIS IS THE PART NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(THE NEXT LINE)    
    players["player" + i].html.score = document.getElementById("player_score_number_" + i);

    playerScoreDiv.innerHTML += "pts";

}
```

for some reason when I try to access:

```
function changeScore(){
  players.player1.html.score.textContent = 30;
}
```

It would change the inside the object but it will not render on the webpage.

Please help.

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML += ...` to update your container element, because it will recreate the elements inside the container and break your references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reassigning an HTML string to `playerScoreDiv.innerHTML`, you lose all the element objects that you had previously created as descendants of `playerScoreDiv`: they are recreated (with obviously different object references) from the HTML.

So instead of:

```
playerScoreDiv.innerHTML += "pts";
```

do:

```
playerScoreDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('pts'));
```